# Check null database value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Below is the object returned from backend:

```
[Object]0: Object Option_Name_0: null Option_Name_1: "me" Option_Name_2: "you" Option_Name_3: "get" Option_Name_4: "no"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

I am just trying to populate the values into dropdown menu, by removing "null" value.

```
$.each(e, function(i) {
    $.each(e[i], function(key, val) {
        if (val != 'null') {
            $(".flash_bet_win").append("<option value=" + val + ">" + val + "</option>");

        }

    });
});
```

But still I see "null" value in dropdown menu. How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it is a string and not `null`

Comment: Remove the quotes from around `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for null not "null",

```
if(val !== null)
            {
                 $(".flash_bet_win").append("<option value="+val+">"+val+"</option>");

            }
```

> go for a deep comparison (!==) not (!=) as `undefined == null` would result in truthy value whereas `undefined === null` would be false

In case you want to check if the value is not null, not undefined or not empty use,

```
if(val){
    ...... //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement, you're checking that that it's not equal to string `'null'`, when you want to check if it's equal to the value `null`

```
if(val != null)
```

Or, even shorter:

```
if(val)
```

Does this do the trick?